# Can a function type accept intersected types as arguments in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, method-signature

Say I've got these types defined:

```js
export type Event = {
  name: EventName,
  timestamp: Timestamp,
};

export type EventWithMetadata = Event & {
  deviceId: ID,
};
```

I'm looking to define a common function interface like so:

```js
export type SideEffect = (event: Event, run?: Run) => Partial<Run>;
```

and using it with this function

```js
// Note: many of these side-effect functions exist, with multiple specializations of the base Event
// type as potential arguments. This is just one example.
const updateTiming: SideEffect = (event: EventWithMetadata, run) => {
  log.debug('updateTiming: %j', event);
  return {
    lastUpdated: event.timestamp,
    deviceId: event.deviceId,
  };
};
```

but then I hit this error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(event: EventWithMetadata, run: Run | undefined) => { startTime: number; deviceId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SideEffect'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'EventWithMetadata'.
      Property 'deviceId' is missing in type 'Event' but required in type '{ deviceId: string; }'.
```

which makes sense: Typescript thinks I'm trying to downcast `Event` into `EventWithMetadata`, which obviously can't happen.

After a lot of searching on generics and overloads and union types, the best answer I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815239/362703). I really hate the result and wouldn't want to make it a pattern:

```js
const updateTiming: SideEffect = (inputEvent: Event, run) => {
  const event = inputEvent as EventWithMetadata;   // <- This sucks.
  log.debug('updateTiming: %j', event);
  return {
    lastUpdated: event.timestamp,
    deviceId: event.deviceId,
  };
};
```

Are there better solutions than casting?

Comment: The error is trying to warn you about potential unsoundness. Let's say someone wants to call the function of type `SideEffect`. The signature suggests that passing an argument of type `Event` is fine. But your implementation actually wants `EventWithMetadata`. Accessing `event.deviceId` would lead to `undefined` even though it is typed as `ID`.

Comment: To clarify -- `SideEffect` is a function that triggers based on input `Event`s, which have different shapes. I'm trying to say that any `SideEffect` function must at least handle the baseline `Event` arguments, but each `SideEffect` function will handle a special `EventWithMetadata` or `EventWithUserInformation` or `EventWithKetchupAndRelish` event.

I have an object that owns a collection of `SideEffect` functions, which it will call via a mapping of `Event` type names.

Comment: A [mre] would be nice here so we don't have to fake up whatever `Run`, etc, are in order to test.

Comment: Sounds like the typing of the mapping would lead to the real solution of your problem. You should probably include it in the question.

Comment: With the information provided here I'd say you want `SideEffect` to be *generic*, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N728Pw) shows.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, what specifically goes wrong with it? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz you got it! This was the code I'd originally tried with generics:

```export type SideEffect = <Type extends Event>(event: Type, run?: Run) => Partial<Run>;```

This is the correct code:

```export type SideEffect<Type extends Event> = (event: Type, run?: Run) => Partial<Run>;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Though, adding for others that it looks like defining an array of these `SideEffect` functions leads to the need for [existential generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129942/362703)

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer, although if you have an array of these things you need some way to distinguish which events to dispatch to which ones, which might *not* require existential generics.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't belabor the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `updateTiming` to handle `EventWithMetadata` specifically, then the type of `updateTiming` needs to know about `EventWithMetadata`.  In order for `SideEffect` to know about `EventWithMetadata` and still work with other `Event` types, you probably want it to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the particular subtype of `Event` that it handles:

```
type SideEffect<T extends Event> =
    (event: T, run?: Run) => Partial<Run>;
```

Then `updateTiming` is a `SideEffect<EventWithMetadata>` and not just a `SideEffect`:

```
const updateTiming: SideEffect<EventWithMetadata> = (event, run) => {
    console.debug('updateTiming: %j', event);
    return {
        lastUpdated: event.timestamp,
        deviceId: event.deviceId,
    };
}; // okay
```

Note that it's not possible to hold onto a `SideEffect` without knowing what it handles, but that's a *good* thing, because otherwise you could actually pass it the wrong `Event`.  If you think you need a `SideEffect[]` without a type argument, then you will have to refactor so that you can distinguish events and event handlers somehow via a test (ideally both handlers and events would be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) but otherwise you could write [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)).  But that's out of scope for this question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxA9mpBvAUDpBSAlsAC4QBOAZgsgKIBuEZAcuMlkiAFxICMSAL75CJctVpIAKkUhRS4GNiQAjXgCYhIgmMo1ESAJIARZfF4BmLYWJk9kgEoBXYMoAmvPgBokAGxDyAKowbiDkHlzAAJ4+bhAMRIiGESDRWtpIEAAeMGgUpEikUTD0TGRIALzYGTagkLyMzKRskF41hKSy0ApgMLwycj0wbTaCANx4Ntm5+YXFpU0A6kSkABYAshAKoQqVSI3lAGTVNjZxCUkRJiOE43gZ03kFRSVIAMpEcXRUVBDwpAAeKSZLLkYBuKD7MqkAB8lXaBAAFPEmv0fBQXAB+XjOYAASkqcIACiB8kQQL4AbiYRMMvA0MB5EgnCEwhABiQAOa8D5fH5-QEHUjLNabbZhEBwqrI6HolwEipw3CnQj0xloXwQAB0cRUTk5iIA5CyduzZFzeABSABWhp8KLIeImKoIFC2TgormVLps-iCrPCvAdpC1nUGihuPoI50SEGSQehOviseSkdOd1GtJwwjq0DgBiJaCgUCIKk1Dgg+lIeS56xAURUHEmojsEgMQsh3pVJrZHOA3PcycuvBM1hdaDWlCFvE4VAwvHkFC5Y4IwhsujbyAG3UUyjUSE0a5b4n0yFHnHMSCsR50rdPSFx7k8Pj9pGCppS0ViQ7jn6i6RsF4FjIAEAGkQTBCEkAAawgKI0CoKEmkhKpYPgxCOylZQAG0iVsJBQIAXRnBEkFzXgiTTQCunkRR+hooY00EJBjg7XDCKEbCiObAggPeT4IG+X5-jAiDmCgtCEKQsgUJguCpMwvYu1OXD8KIkio0IGVUWkwEiRhOVgGxB95Qo0lOgpKkXAM0janYCjSJvTjuJ4pA1SZHtyD7AdeUE-kRIAIk8s0wC5AKsO0shDIVJVSPcjVtV1fUjWC7yrVte1oSdUi3VID0vVswhX3fNkImDUMGIjQrox-eNMkTGNLio25nVuDJUvNfstVzPYgoDEKwtpGx3IKVZUjcTUoCFPZROySDIUkjDoSgGFEXIgifBLPlhNIHkBKEgU8QXfb-IKIhIToUEKAQQFfIO-4fDu06wJhKU4S2vydu69hKgqKpcyGwgqBcf4iAZJAxvBTUhVm0FxIW+SluQ1bgwaaEXs2k6dqgPbtoFbDCIJZSbA++7SCgLU5woOgEFWREoGQRUTk04hEMRSGJugIVIpDXNNogPECQZnnsp9QQ8QyYRsyAA)